# Using categories on navigation bar instead of pages

Tags: navigation

Check this URL [www.linuxstall.com](http://www.linuxstall.com). The top navigation bar has one page (about us). I want the categories there, not pages. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're dealing with a recent version of Wordpress it should be pretty straightforward.

- In your Wordpress admin panel, select Appearance->Menus.
- Create a new menu. In the current wordpress there's a little plus sign at the top, enter a new menu name, and then click create menu.
- On the bottom left there should be a little widget titled Categories that has your categories. Drag categories from there to your new menu.
- Save the menu.
- In the upper left there's a Theme Locations widget that allows you to select a menu.